# UINavigationController displayed modally doesn't release memory when dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

I am having trouble with memory management when presenting a UINavigationController containing a UITableViewController as a modal view. I autorelease both the UINavigationController and the UITableViewController, but when I open and then close the modal view while using the Allocations Instrument, the memory that the view creates is not released when closed.

```
- (void)showOptions {
     OptionsViewController *optionsViewController = [[[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:optionsViewController] autorelease];
     navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
         navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
     }
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissOptions) name:@"dismissOptions" object:nil];
     [[(ApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController] presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}

- (void)dismissOptions {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"dismissOptions" object:nil];
     [[(ApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when/where is the "dismissOptions" notification posted? Is it posted at all? Is whatever self points to in your code alive? Does it receive the notification? And perhaps most importantly, what problem does this notification solve?

Modal view controllers are automatically retained, so code like this should suffice:

```
- (void)showOptions {
    OptionsViewController *optionsViewController = [[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionsViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:optionsViewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [optionsViewController release];
    [navController release];
}
```

and then in OptionsViewController, or any other view controller that might dismiss the modal view:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

(note that using self suffices here, as a call to dismissModalViewControllerAnimated bubbles up to the view controller that originally presented the modal view controller)